# Tried hack to force 4.2 update, result is a broken play store. Theories?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, samsung-galaxy-nexus, system-error

So I'm on a Galaxy Nexus.  Still on 4.1.  I tried the 'hack' where you clear data on the Google Services Framework, then check update, but no luck.  I shrugged and got on with my day.

Now I'm noticing that I have several updates in the play store.  And if I choose "update" all I get is an instant "Update for [app name] could not be downloaded".  Repeatedly.

I've tried clearing data for the play store, rebooting, but nothing.

Yay. Any theories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove and add again your Google (main) user account. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you good sir. I knew I'd done it before and that there was some easy fix, that's the one.